# Nodejs based jest test keeps failing

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

I am trying learn to use `jest` and `supertest` to run my `api` test. It is my first time and I am following a tutorial. However, my test has refused to work. I am getting these errors:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 80000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

And this error at the same time:

```
st did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

 This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. 
 Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

I have tried `npm test --detectOpenHandles` to see the asyn operations that werent stopped but I didnt see any.

I am making a test of my API routes. Here is my test:

```
 const request = require('supertest')

 describe('Test POST /register', ()=>{


test('It should respond with 200 success', async ()=>{
    const response = await request(app).post('/register');
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    
},80000);

test('It should catch password must be present', ()=>{});
```

The route that I am testing:

```
router.post('/register', register);
```

The `app.js` file:

```
const authRoute = require("./routes/auths")
```

My `server.js` file:

```
const server = http.createServer(app);


 const start = async () => {
 try {
 await connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URL)
  server.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}...`)
 );
 } catch (error) {

 }
 };

start();
```

It is a MERN stack with redis database instance. The redis is used to store users' refresh tokens
How can I fix this?

Comment: try the done() callback : async (done)=>{ .... done() }

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. It is still the same errors. Not working

Comment: try   afterAll(async () => {
    await app.close();
  }); that worked on nestJs last time i got that error

Comment: This should come at the end of the test?

Comment: at the same level as your 'describe', but it doesn't matter if it's before or after it

Comment: Got this error:  Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: app.close is not a function

Comment: how are you instantiating the 'app'  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249176/discussion-between-rami-dridi-and-thatkingz-thatkingz).